# PLSQL Developer. Grayed out "Preference" menu item

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

[image: Preference]

I cannot click the preference button on Pl/SQL Developer. Though I am connected and I am able to run scripts. I need to adjust somethings in the pls/sql Developer, but I am not able.
Doest anyone know the solution?

Comment: What application are you using as your IDE? PL/SQL is a language not an application.

Comment: @ChrisProsser: `PLSQL Developer` is the name of an IDE: http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this changelog](http://www.allroundautomations.com/pls80rc2.txt), this bug was fixed in version 8.0 Beta 5: "Preferences menu could be disabled on first start".

According to [this thread](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=39239&PHPSESSID=2e3c1b028a66500ae8a1730abc88b993), you need to make sure that this directory exists and you can write to it: `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\PLSQL Developer\Preferences\<user>`.

Comment: Jonearles.. I dont have a folder called aplication data in my user folder. However the preferences exists in program file 86x under the name administrator (the name is moudiz, and I cant find a the file with my name) and the both file are writiable. What should I do now ?

Comment: Go to Help -> Support Info, there's a Preferences section that should list the directories and files the software is looking for.  Create the necessary folder and copy the files.  Then try granting read/write access to the files.

Comment: joes the directory exists and they are NOT read only.. what to do now ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix this problem.  You should probably post this question to the [PL/SQL Developer forum](http://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=postlist&Board=3).  It's a pretty good forum, you'll likely get a response from one of the developers.  Or if you want to take another shot at fixing it yourself, you could try downloading Process Monitor and it might tell you want folder and file PL/SQL Developer is trying to access.